# Parsing JSON with mutiple JSON Arrays

Tags: android, json

I am having trouble parsing JSON when there is multiple arrays. This is an example of the JSON:

```
{
   "topics":[
      {
         "posts":[
            {
               "date":"01/01/01 01:01",
               "user":"Example",
               "subject":"Example Topic #1",
               "contents":"Hello!"
            },
            {
               "date":"01/01/01 01:01",
               "user":"Example",
               "subject":"Example Reply #1",
               "contents":"Hello!"
            },
            {
               "date":"01/01/01 01:01",
               "user":"Example",
               "subject":"Example Reply #2",
               "contents":"Hello!"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "posts":[
            {
               "date":"01/01/01 01:01",
               "user":"Example",
               "subject":"Example Topic #2",
               "contents":"Hello!"
            },
            {
               "date":"01/01/01 01:01",
               "user":"Example",
               "subject":"Example Reply #1",
               "contents":"Hello!"
            },
            {
               "date":"01/01/01 01:01",
               "user":"Example",
               "subject":"Example Reply #2",
               "contents":"Hello!"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

In each of the `posts` array the first one is the main topic itself and then the rest are replies, the amount of replies is varied and this is just an example.

What I am looking to do is take the `user`, `subject` and `contents` from the main post, the replies I want to ignore.

What I have tried so far after looking at some tutorials is:

```
try {
    JSONArray threads = jo.getJSONArray(THREADS_TAG); // jo is a JSONObject parameter.

    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = threads.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject post = c.getJSONObject(POSTS_TAG);

        Log.i(TAG, "Name: " + post.getString(NAME_TAG));
    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception:");
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I am having problems with this and I am getting an exception:

> at posts of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: you need to getJSONObject(0) to obtain the first object of the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
try {
    JSONArray threads = jo.getJSONArray("topics");

    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray posts = threads.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("posts");
        user[i]=posts.getJSONObject(0).getString("user");
        subject[i]=posts.getJSONObject(0).getString("subject");
        contents[i]=posts.getJSONObject(0).getString("contents");
    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception:");
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: For the part, `threads.getJSONArray("posts")`, `getJSONArray()` will only take an integer as the parameter.

Comment: @DanielB I am sorry, my mistake. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change for JsonArray parsing as:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < threads.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject cjsontopic = threads.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray jsonarrayposts=cjsontopic.getJSONArray("posts");

        for (int j = 0; j < jsonarrayposts.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject cjsontopic = jsonarrayposts.getJSONObject(j);
        String strpost = cjsontopic.getString(POSTS_TAG);

        String struser = cjsontopic.getString("user");
        String strsubject = cjsontopic.getString("subject");
        String strcontents = cjsontopic.getString("contents");
        //... get other elemets
        Log.i(TAG, "Name: " +strpost);
     }

   }
```

currently you are trying to get String in JsonObject your Json format is just like `JsonObject-->JsonArray-->JsonObject-->JsonArray-->JsonObject-->getString`